# Exception when trying iterate Excel range.value like array ? (Help Debug)

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, interop

I tried the following : (VB.Net code)

```
Dim data As Object
Dim range As Excel.Range
range = WB.Sheets("mysheet").Range("A1:C5")
data = range.Value   ' Here WB is the Wrokbook object
' Until here its working fine.
' During Debug: I can see data with values for [ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), .. ]
' Now following line gives an exception !!
Dim val = data(0,0)  ' Index out of range exception.
```

How can I iterate the so called `RangeValueDataType` object like an array ?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238606(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIAK Excel Range data is array with 1 base index, i.e. first item will be `data(1, 1)`.

Comment: But please explain:
When I applied a watch on `data`, it shows elements starting with (0,0) why ?

I will try data(1,1) and get back.

Comment: Thanks, it really worked. But then it should not show (0,0) in debug.
Its frustrating. Explain if you can why did that showed me (0,0) ?

Comment: Can't say for sure why it shows you it that way. It correctly showed me it as array with 1 based index, I used C# and VS 2008 SP1 then I worked with it.